# How to overcome floating point exception error

Tags: c

```
modulus = number[mul1_count] % prime_array[prime1_count];
```

when my code executes this line i get Floating point exception, how to overcome this ,both the arrays are of type int

Comment: Are you sure you are getting a floating point exception? If both arrays are of type int, then you could get a division by zero exception, if prime_array[prime1_count] is every zero.

Comment: it's always best to include the full error message and enough context for us to help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is this a floating point exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081250/why-is-this-a-floating-point-exception)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure `prime_array[prime1_count]` is not zero.